# How do I add a Scala variable's value to a jsValue in Play?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Let's say I have  `val numOpen = 5`.

Now I have a JsValue that has a key whose value needs to be the value of numOpen:

StackOverflow says there's too much code for this post, even though it's not really a lot. See the full JSON [here](https://gist.github.com/LCBecker/23051712b7829846bb46).

How do I insert the value of a Scala variable as "value"'s value in this JSON? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Play `JsObject` as a `++` method, you can cast the `JsValue` and update the field:

```
val numOpen = 5
var data1: JsValue = Json.parse( """
  {
    "value": 64, // THIS REALLY NEEDS TO BE "value" : numOpen
    "color":"#F7464A",
    "highlight": "#FF5A5E",
    "label": "Open"
  }
  """)

val t: JsObject = data1.as[JsObject] ++ Json.obj("value" -> numOpen)
```

You can cast it back to `JsValue` if you want:

```
t.as[JsValue]
```

If you have nested values the only approach I know of is using nested `Json.obj`

```
var data1: JsValue = Json.parse( """
  {
    "value": 64,
    "color":"#F7464A",
    "highlight": "#FF5A5E",
    "label": {
      "value": 54
    }
  }
""")


val t: JsObject = data1.as[JsObject] ++ Json.obj("label" -> Json.obj("value" -> 5))

println(t.as[JsValue].toString())
```

Outputs:

```
{"value":64,"color":"#F7464A","highlight":"#FF5A5E","label":{"value":5}}
```

I don't know if there are easier way to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like this is close, but it's still not working yet. It might be because the real `var data1` are lists of 3 sets of value, color, highlight, and label. I'm not sure how to update the value for a specific set.

Comment: Can you add the real json to the question?

Comment: The real json is [here](https://gist.github.com/LCBecker/23051712b7829846bb46). Thanks for your help, @Ende-Neu! I appreciate it!

Comment: Well, you can access the value using `as[JsArray]` but it's very hard to reconstruct the Json with the changed value then, probably somebody else has a better idea.